# How to create pull request from Mercurial bookmark on Bitbucket?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, bitbucket, bookmarks

It is possible to push Mercurial bookmarks to Bitbucket, but does anybody know how to create pull requests from them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on information from [this thread](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issue/6705/cant-create-pull-request-from-hg-bookmark) (thanks **sirex** for sum up). It is not user friendly, but possible.

- make sure you know `thename` of your bookmark
- open https://bitbucket.org/yourname/yourproject/branch/thename
- note the hash

[image: bookmark hash]

- push <kbd>Pull request</kbd> button and make sure the hash in drop down matches
- that's it

Comment: I just tried this and could NOT get it to work UNLESS the bookmark I'm trying to create a pull request for is itself a head.  So if you have a linear change, say:  A --- B (bookmarked feature-1) --- C (bookmarked feature-2) , you will not be able to create a PR for feature-1's hash (since it's not a head).

Answer (score 5):

I'm using bookmarks for pull requests quite actively with my team, for a few weeks. Here how it works for me:

1. Create bookmark, called `master` on `default` branch:

   ```
   hg bo master -r default
   ```

   If you don't do this, then after creating two branches on `default`, when one is named with bookmark, then other will be left as anonymous branch. So `master` bookmark is needed to name this anonymous branch.
2. Make this `master` branch public in your fork repository and in upstream repository:

   ```
   hg push -B master
   hg push upstream -B master
   ```

   You can manage repository aliases in `.hg/hgrc` file (relative to your repository), example:

   ```
   [paths]
   default = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/foo/upstream
   upstream = ssh://hg@bitbucket.org/upstream/upstream
   ```
3. Ask your team to pull `master` bookmark:

   ```
   hg pull -B master
   ```
4. Start to work on a feature, using bookmark:

   ```
   hg bo feature-1
   hg ci -m "Some changes."
   hg push
   ```
5. In Bitbucket, press "Pull request" button, or type "x" then "p".
6. On left side, select you branch, to create pull request from it. If your `default` has only one branch (to check that, see `hg heads default`), then your bookmark branch will be displayed as `default`, but if you have more than one branch on `default`, then you will see some think like this `default (0932c9ab2029)`, you can find correct one by matching hash value from `hg bo`. After selecting branch, pull request title will be filled with last commit from selected branch.
7. Press "Create pull request" button at the bottom, and that's it, your pull request will be created.
8. To create new pull request, first pull changes from upstream repository:

   ```
   hg pull upstream
   ```
9. Update to `master`:

   ```
   hg up master
   ```
10. And start your new feature branch using bookmark:

    ```
    hg bo feature-2
    ```

If you don't have possibility, to ask your team, to use `master` bookmark as a bookmark to original `default`, then I would suggest you to create you personal named branch for example named as your nickname, and work with bookmarks using your personal named branch instead of working on `default`. In this case work flow will be this:

1. Create your personal named branch:

   ```
   hg branch nickname
   hg ci -m "Starting my personal branch for feature branch management."
   ```
2. Create local `master` bookmark:

   ```
   hg bo master
   ```
3. Start to work on a feature, using bookmark:

   ```
   hg bo feature-1
   hg ci -m "Some changes."
   hg push
   ```
4. In Bitbucket, press "Pull request" button, or type "x" then "p".
5. On left side, select you branch, to create pull request from it. If your `nickname` named branch has only one head (to check that, see `hg heads nickname`), then your bookmark branch will be displayed as `nickname`, but if you have more than one branch on `nickname`, then you will see some think like this `nickname (0932c9ab2029)`, you can find correct one by matching hash value from `hg bo`. After selecting branch, pull request title will be filled with last commit from selected branch.
6. Press "Create pull request" button at the bottom, and that's it, your pull request will be created.
7. To create new pull request, first pull changes from upstream repository:

   ```
   hg pull upstream
   ```
8. Update to `master`:

   ```
   hg up master
   ```
9. Merge `default` to `master`

   ```
   hg merge default
   hg ci -m merge
   ```
10. And start your new feature branch using bookmark:

    ```
    hg bo feature-2
    ```

Comment: It is much more recommended to use @ as the equivalent of master branch in Git. The @ bookmark is special because it is activated by default on new clones.